# USB-C for power output when using PoE+ HAT

Tags: usb-power, poe, usb-c

When using the PoE+ HAT with the raspberry pi 4B, would it be possible to use the USB-C port as a power output, rather than a power input, for instance for an extra fan when the GPIO pins aren't available?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see? Or even study the published schematics.

Comment: don't use the RPi as a power supply ... it can easily become an expensive fuse

Comment: @jsotola then what do you recommend for 2 racks with 2 fans?